# How can I control the configuration that netplan generates?

Tags: networking, netplan

Say I want to run a certain command after netplan has done its magic and started the network. In my case, I need to run a command to add a special "onlink" route, which netplan doesn't support yet.

But I have no clue where to begin. I know I need to use systemd, to have some directive that makes the service run after networking has been configured.

Any pointers, appreciated!

Comment: Does this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/cause-a-script-to-execute-after-networking-has-started help you further?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Netplan "While the netplan configuration does not include support for hook scripts, you can add systemd unit jobs with the appropriate Requires: and After: fields to run arbitrary commands once the network is up."

Comment: @TomášPospíšek While it looked hopeful, it doesn't seem like netplan triggers any systemd states to change for scripts to know when to run :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The on-link options is now available in netplan 0.34:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/0.34
https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1735193

There is currently no way to add "hooks" for the netplan steps, nor are we planning to add hook support in netplan itself. When a feature is missing, you should open a bug report against netplan (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/+filebug) so we can see if it's a common enough case to add it, or you can use the files generated by netplan directly by copying them into /etc/systemd/network/ (for networkd) or /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections (for NetworkManager), and removing the entries from your netplan config.

There are however plans to come up with a proper solution for users who need to run hook scripts for when the network is coming up though, or going down -- I'll update this answer / the netplan.io website once that's available. Using systemd units one should be able to control the network's behavior.